# JSON object manipulation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Let's suppose that we have the following JSON Object that describes a Person:

```
{
 "firstName": "John",
 "lastName": "Smith",
 "age": 25,
 "address":
 {
     "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
     "city": "New York",
     "state": "NY",
     "postalCode": "10021"
 },
 "phoneNumber":
 [
     {
       "type": "home",
       "number": "212 555-1234"
     },
     {
       "type": "fax",
       "number": "646 555-4567"
     }
 ]
```

}

Can someone suggest the most elegant and most efficient way to manipulate the previous object in Rails 3?

I want to be able to:

1. Add another element like "firstname","lastname", etc .
2. Remove an existing element
3. Change an element without removing it or adding a new one. (eg. change firstname to "Nick")

Thanks in advance.

PS. I prefer to manipulate it in the Controller!

Comment: can you give a bit more context? For example, where are you looking to manipulate it? in the controller, in javascript, in your kitchen while making a latte?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

just parse it and change it

```
hash = JSON.parse(json_data)
hash["firstname"] = "John"
hash.delete("lastname")
new_json = hash.to_json
```

P.S. JSON.parse might not work - it depends on which JSON library you're using. try this instead:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json_data)
```

Comment: What if I want to remove or edit or add a field to address ? For example deleting "streetAddress" field? Can you give an example for that as well?

Comment: nested objects are parsed as well so simply do hash["address"]["streetAddress"]="42" and hash["address"].delete("city")